# Масштабирование контента сайта

Tags: css3

Сверстал сайт без `bootstrap`, `flex` и т.д., на мониторе с разрешением 1920х1080, 1:1 всё хорошо.

Перенёс на ноутбук с разрешением экрана 1920х1080, 1:1,25 все поплыло.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно использовать, чтобы контент контейнера масштабировался.

Answer (score 0):

На сайт то посмотреть можно ?
Flex и сам прекрасно масштабируется - если все размеры / отступы / flex-basis указаны корректно